# What is the best FREE orb for java

Tags: java, soap, corba

I'm thinking about to use CORBA to make some interoperable applications with each other.

In sometime, there will be much request (Ex: 10,000 req/trasaction) then I've discards using SOAP.

I've seen ICE from zeroc ([Differences between Ice and CORBA](http://www.zeroc.com/iceVsCorba.html)) but I don't trust in ICE completely because it isn't based on a standard and is developed by a company and not a community.

So, I'm looking for free-open-source CORBA implementation binding to Java, but I don't know what is the best.

Could you tell me your opinions? I'm crazy?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's not the answer you want, but I would recommend to use something else than CORBA.

Your're right that SOAP comes with a lot of overhead, but the problem with having to deal with many transaction is often not the protocol you use, but the programming model.

So, have you thought about using a RESTstyle application? (JAX-RS, part of Java EE 6)
When being stateless you are usually able to handle many parallel requests, since you don't need session information per client. This of course has to fit your overall design, since using an RMI approach as you planned usually is preferred when having coarse grained use cases and dialogues with the other system instead of small independent operations.

Comment: Yes, I think like you, but I lose to approaches: other side instantiations (useful sometimes), and efficiency in the communication. With rest I must serialize/deserialize all information, and if I must send complex information in a call, it could be a problem. So I prefer CORBA, but I don't know which is the best free implementation.